# ACF: How to get the full field name (meta_key) by a field key?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields, user-meta

In Advanced Custom Fields: Which function can I use to get the full meta key of a field by its field key?

So, if I have a field with the name `some_field` and the field key `field_sd54hfs5df`: How do I get the name by the key?

I found the function `acf_get_fields()` and `acf_get_field()`, but when using field types like `group`, `flexibel_content` or `repeater` the names in the returned arrays are not the full names that are stored in the meta database tables.

For example, when a group has the name `some_group` and the field `some_field` the mentioned functions only return `some_group` or `some_field`, but not the full `meta_key`, which is `some_group_some_field`.

Unfortunately subfields of such a field type are not returned, so I don't see an option to reformat the returned arrays to combine the arrays recursively to built up the full meta key names.

---

I have written the below method to fetch the field name as stored under the `_some-field…` metadata by ACF, but when working in an environment with trash metadata and old records this is fetching multiple records, so that isn't a solution.

```php
/**
 * Get a meta key name by a ACF field key
 * 
 * @since 1.0.22
 * 
 * @param string $key
 * @return null|string
 */
public function getUserMetaKey(string $key): ?string
{
    global $wpdb;
    $select = "SELECT distinct meta_key FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_value = '$key' AND meta_key NOT LIKE 'acfe_form_actions_%'";
    // Debug::log($select);
    $usermeta = $wpdb->get_results($select);
    // Debug::log($usermeta);
    if (count($usermeta) > 0) {
        $metaKey = $usermeta[0]->meta_key;
        $metaKey = ltrim($metaKey, '_');
        return $metaKey;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to achieve this but here's one which supports an unknown depth of children, for example where you have nested groups within groups.

Given the field key "field_{some_hash}" of the field, this function will retrieve the field, and its parent most field, and so on until we reach the top of the field tree.

```php
function custom_acf_get_field_name_by_key( $key ) {

    $field = acf_maybe_get_field( $key );

    if ( empty( $field ) || ! isset( $field['parent'], $field['name'] ) ) {
        return $field;
    }

    $ancestors = array();

    while ( ! empty( $field['parent'] ) && ! in_array( $field['name'], $ancestors ) ) {

        $parent = acf_get_field( $field['parent'] );

        $ancestors[] = $field['name'];

        $field = $parent;

    }

    $formatted_key = array_reverse( $ancestors );
    $formatted_key = implode( '_', $formatted_key );

    return "_$formatted_key";

}
```

Assume a case where I have a nested group:

```
 - dev_group_test | field_61ecf308ded3e | group
   ∟ title        | field_61ecf316ded3f | text
   ∟ location     | field_61ecf31cded40 | text
   ∟ sub_group    | field_61ecfa1fe5894 | group
     ∣
     ∟ sub_group_title | field_61ecfa2de5895 | text
```

If I want the full key of `sub_group_title`:

```
$meta_key = custom_acf_get_field_name_by_key( 'field_61ecfa2de5895' );
// result = _dev_group_test_sub_group_sub_group_title
```

If I want the full key of `location`:

```
$meta_key = custom_acf_get_field_name_by_key( 'field_61ecf31cded40' );
// result = _dev_group_test_location
```

NOTE: there may be more efficient ways to do this

Comment: Legendary, thank you so much!
Note that in the `while`-loop, `$field['parent'] > 0` doesn't seem to work for me, but `!empty($field['parent'])` does the job.

Comment: @user1134827 You're welcome. I slapped it together quickly so maybe there is an edge case bug there, does your `debug.log` throw any warnings/errors? `$field['parent'] > 0` is probably not needed anyway, I think, because IIRC every field returns a parent include the top most field, i.e. it always belongs to a parent post object that is stored in the *_posts table. So you can probably do away with that.

Comment: Really appreciate it . `debug.log` is empty. Seems like when using `$field['parent'] > 0` I got a blank `_` (only 1 underscore), removing the condition returns a `__foo_bar` (2 underscores + field name) and using the `!empty($field['parent'])` returns `_foo_bar` (1 underscore + field name).